# Using INDEX-MATCH with interchangeable strings

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

I have two tables I need to cross-reference using a column for names, but some of them are inverted between the two tables, for example :

```
Bob;Bill
Bill;Bob
```

Is there a way to make INDEX-MATCH not care about the position of those two strings in relation to ";", or use a custom function or VBA for it? I've made a convoluted workaround with IFs/LEFT/RIGHT/LEN but it's really not practical, also since I have a different column with more than 2 strings which I would like to use this for if possible. Alternatively, does anyone know of a way to split strings, as such that I can use OR(XYZ("Bob;Bill";";")) and it creates a list of possible permutations?

Thank you

Comment: We are going to need more info, please add to the data what you are trying to search and what you are trying to return.

Comment: "not care about the position of those two strings" > why not just : `if(<formula1works>, <formula1>,if(<formula2works>,<formula2>,<displaySomeNomatchError>))`